# EF Core: how to enforce that a one-to-zero-or-one relation is a member of a one-to-many relation?

Tags: entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

`Foo` has a one-to-many relationship with `Bar`. `Foo` optionally has a default `Bar`, which must be a `Bar` that references this `Foo`.

How can I enforce that the one-to-zero-or-one relation is a member of the one-to-many relation?

Here's one way to design the entities:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    public int? DefaultBarId { get; set; }
    public Bar? DefaultBar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

With this design, the problem is enforcing that `Foo.DefaultBar` is a member of `Bars`.

Here's a different approach:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public bool Default { get; set; }
}
```

With this design, the problem is enforcing that only zero or one member of `Bars` can be marked as `Default`.

Can either of these designs be enforced in the database, and can I express this with the EF Core fluent API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce this relationship with your custom logic (with `Bar` having no `Default` property).

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    private int? _defaultBarId;
    public int? DefaultBarId
    {
        get => _defaultBarId;
        set {
            if (value != _defaultBarId && value is not null) {
                if (Bars?.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BarId == value) is { } bar) {
                    _defaultBarId = value;
                    _defaultBar = bar;
                } else {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The Bar assigned as default does not exist in this Foo");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Bar? _defaultBar;
    public Bar? DefaultBar
    {
        get => _defaultBar;
        set {
            DefaultBarId = value?.BarId;
        }
    }
}
```

To make it watertight, you would also have to add it logic to the setter of `FooId` and `Foo` in `Bar`.

Comment: Is that a "no" on enforcing it in the database?

Comment: Chat GPT has found this solution: `modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
    .HasIndex(e => new { e.GroupColumn, e.DefaultColumn })
    .IsUnique()
    .HasFilter("[Default] = 1");`
This will create a unique index on the combination of GroupColumn and DefaultColumn, but only include records where Default is true. In your case `GroupColumn` is `FooId` in the `Bar` table.

Comment: I don't want to like Chat GPT, but that's exactly the solution I came to myself.